# Set Value to QComboBox from QStringList

Tags: c++, qt4, qcombobox

In my Qt C++ GUI application I have a QDialog window, there I have a few line-edits and I am setting the display texts by function call and setText(). I have stored the values in a QStringList (the QStringList I am populating via Database Query) and setting text as follows--

```
void MyDialog::setDataToForm(QStringList sl)
{
        ui->nameLineEdit->setText(sl[0]);
        ui->emailLineEdit->setText(sl[1]);
}
```

Now, I have a `QComboBox` as well (GenderComboBox). I have set three items there - Male, Female, Other (through QT Creater Layout editor). In my `QStringList sl`, this value is getting saved in `sl[2]`.

How can I set the value of `sl[2]` to `QComboBox` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `currentIndex` of the `QComboBox`:

```
QStringList genderList;
genderList << "Male" << Female" << "Other";
ui->genderComboBox->setCurrentIndex(genderList.indexOf(sl[2]));
```

While this works for your example, I suggest having a look at the samples provided in the Qt documentation ([Books example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-books-example.html), [SQL Widget Mapper Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-sqlwidgetmapper-example.html)) which use models to automatically populate widget contents  based on SQL tables.

Comment: thanx a ton for the link.. qt has extensive documentation, I sometime feel a bit lost in all these.. the link provided better solution to my problem..